# Unit testing conditional comments

Tags: java, html, testing, conditional-comments, xmlunit

I'm using XMLUnit (*org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff*) to test two HTML strings: one is produced by templating engine, other is from a static file. It works fine, but I ran to following problem:

There are conditional comments in my code, like this:

```
<!--[if IE6]>
    <link type="text/css" href="ie6Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
```

I get an error if I test it against following code (href and type attributes are swapped in following snipped):

```
<!--[if IE6]>
    <link href="ie6Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
```

I know that for XML parser, the conditional comment is just a plain text. But is there a way how to test conditional comment content a HTML/XML code?

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to ignore the comments, there is `XMLUnit.setIgnoreComments(false)`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<!--[if IE6]>` and `<![endif]-->` before running the test.

Comment: That's a nice idea. But it doesn't solve my problem entirely, since I need to test various conditional definitions, too. Perhaps I might test content of conditional comments in separate test, though.